# Blue "Loading" Icon on Recently Added SharePoint Files

Tags: 2013, document-library, new-indicator

What is the blue "loading" icon on SharePoint files after they've been dropped into a SharePoint folder? Instead of having the little green icon with the check mark, it's a blue icon with arrows that look like the file is loading.

I'm using SharePoint for a construction company that hired me to scan and save their safety paperwork into SharePoint, so I need to know for sure if the files are being loaded and saved so everyone can access the files.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using OneDrive? If so, then [see page 138 from the book "SharePoint 2013 How-To"](https://books.google.com/books?id=BOh5R-C28BYC&pg=PA138&lpg=PA138&dq=sharepoint%202013%20blue%20icon%20document%20library&source=bl&ots=E8It8jKyrf&sig=7DEjpbWeIfe6ogZDMstLIJ29Guo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFAQ6AEwCWoVChMIzuSsytLHxwIVTjaICh32Qgsd#v=onepage&q=sharepoint%202013%20blue%20icon%20document%20library&f=false) - it talks about how the blue icon in the shape of two round arrows pointing at each other means that the documents are still synchronizing.